# Firebase Autentication OpenId Configuration for TikTok

Tags: firebase, authentication, openid, tiktok

I'm trying to add TikTok to firebase custom authentication (openid). I have already created app in tiktok developers account and have the client id and secret.

I dont know where I can find the two remaining fields

- Name
- Issuer Url

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase wants to connect to your custom OIDC provider. So you have to pass the parameters of the OIDC provider of your choice. You'll use this if you already have a SSO server, and firebase needs to validate the tokens at your OIDC provider.